# WUSA catastrophic failure 0x8000ffff when called from system() VC++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, windows-update

I'm trying to make a Windows Update uninstall program in C++, but whenever I try to call wusa, it exits on a catastrophic failure 0x80000ffff. I call the same command in a Command Prompt and it works perfectly. How do I fix this?

Here is the function I use to call wusa:

```
system("wusa /uninstall /kb:2511455");
```

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/windows-update-error-8000ffff

Comment: That does not fix the issue. The command works perfectly from a command console but running it from system() has problems.

Comment: Pretty likely that you are not running the same wusa.exe that you run from the command line.   When you build your program as a 32-bit executable then you run c:\windows\syswow64\wusa.exe instead of c:\windows\system32\wusa.exe.  Simplest workaround is to build the x64 version of your program.  Next simplest is to run %windows%\sysnative\wusa.exe

Comment: Will the C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\sysnative one run on both x86 and x64?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured out how to solve this issue and I will post my solution for anyone in the future that has the same issue. The system() command was running the 32-bit executable inside %windir%\SysWoW64\ instead of the native 64-bit version. To solve this issue I had to use the following:

```
PVOID OldValue = NULL;
if( Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(&OldValue) ) 
{
    //  Anything in this block uses the system native files and not the WoW64 ones  
    // put native WoW64 code here
    system("wusa /uninstall /kb:2511455");
    //system("wusa /?"); // use this for testing

    //  Immediately re-enable redirection. Note that any resources
    //  associated with OldValue are cleaned up by this call.
    if ( FALSE == Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection(OldValue) )
        {
            //  Failure to re-enable redirection should be considered
            //  a criticial failure and execution aborted.
            return 0;
        }
}
```

Comment: It would be better to check if it is running 32 or 64 bit OS and then running the appropriate  wusa.exe.